# create persistent ubuntu deployment in kubernetes

Tags: ubuntu, docker, kubernetes

i,m trying to create a persistent Ubuntu Kubernetes deployment
my idea was to mount the entire Ubuntu pod file system to a persistent volume
here is what i tried

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ubuntu
  labels:
    app: ubuntu
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ubuntu
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ubuntu
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: ubuntu
          image: ubuntu:latest
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          volumeMounts:
           - mountPath: "/"
             name: task-pv-storage
      volumes:
        - name: task-pv-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
           claimName: task-pv-claim
```

but i get the following error

```
command : kubectl describe pod [Ubuntu-pod]
```

output:

```
Error: Error response from daemon: invalid bind mount spec "/home/moses/test:/:rslave": invalid volume specification: '/home/moses/test:/:rslave': invalid mount config for type "bind": invalid specification: destination can't be '/'
```

any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you want to mount the volume as root?

Comment: because i want to save the entire file system of pod to my persistent volume so any changes in pod's file system will be persistent not just one directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You chose the wrong engine for your task. The best option for you is to use a VM (Virtual Machine). It’s impossible to mount volume as '/'.